# What are the punishments for friendly fire?

Tags: planetside-2

In Planetside 2, friendly fire is extremely common, constantly resulting in a message that asks the player to stop. If friendly fire is continued, the player is warned that his/her weapons will be locked.

How long would my weapons be locked if I continued friendly fire (I've noticed that friendly fire is based primarily on time inflicting damage, rather than damage done)? Are there other punishments for friendly fire, ie. killing an ally resulting in loss of score?

Comment: The punishments are far too lenient, IMHO!  In certain play styles, I find myself getting killed by my own team half the time.  It would be good if people spamming frag grenades into buildings had more reason to stop and consider whether there may be friendlies fighting close-quarters style inside that building that they may kill.  I've been killed like this countless times.

Comment: It might also encourage vehicle, particularly magrider, drivers to drive more carefully through crowds of infantry from their own team.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your weapons will be locked if you continue friendly fire. 
This can be between 1 and 30 minutes, however, you will not know how close you are to having your weapons locked. The only way you can tell you're getting closer to that moment are the messages. After several messages, you will have your weapons locked.

As far as i know, there are no other punishments.